# Parse data from html page to table

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, html

I would like make table of chosen physical properties of elements (for example atomization enthalpy, vaporization enthalpy, heat of vaporization, boiling point), which are accessible on [this page](http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/W.html).

It is a huge pain to do it by hand, and I didn't find any other machine-processing-friendly source of such data on the internet.

I was trying to learn how to to do it in Python (because I want to use this data for my other code written in Python / NumPy / Pandas).

I was able to download the webpage HTML code with urllib2, and I was trying to learn how to use some HTML/XML parser like  ElementTree or MiniDom. However I have no experience with web programing and HTML/XML processing.

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup for this kind of thing, it is way easier to use than the parsers available in the standard lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lxml's xpath support, you can parse the data easily. Here's an example parsing the atomization enthalpy

```
import lxml.html
import urllib2

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/W.html").read()
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
result = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[7]/li[8]")
```

You could dynamically generate the xpath string for the different elements, and use a dict to parse the require fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, raphonic

It was necessary modify your code slightly to get it work, but thanks for kickstart. This code is working:

```
import lxml.html
import lxml.etree
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
infile = opener.open('http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/W.html')
html = infile.read()

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
result = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[7]/li[8]")
print lxml.etree.tostring(result[0])
```

but probably it is not the best one

Anyway. Because the structure of the page for different elements is not exactly the same, I would probably use just simple **string.find()** and **regular expersion**. Like this

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
infile = opener.open('http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/W.html')
page = infile.read()

i = page.find("Heat of Vaporization")
substr = page[i:i+50]
print substr

import re
non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
print non_decimal.sub('', substr)
```